# Cannot provision more Digital Twins instances

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a Digital Twins resource, yet I always get the error below. I have tried to run an example in all sites (West US, East US, etc...), and I always got the same error. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: [I've been experiencing the exact same thing.](https://xkcd.com/979/)  I submitted a ticket to Microsoft Support, but the issue hasn't been resolved yet, at least for any of my accounts (across completely different organizations.)  I suspect you already knew the error message implies something about quotas, but I don't think it's due to _your_ configuration.  I believe something was misconfigured by the Digital Twins's team with the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be you have hit a quota limit on your subscription. You will need to raise a support request (it is free for quota changes) to adjust this.